# How to make TextView print the value from EditText?

Tags: java, android

1. I want the EditText element print the value I have entered in the UserInputs Array.     I have tried Log.v and doInBackground,but that doesn't work.
2. I would be happy if you can explain how do I print the needed value in the EditText in the future, because I'm new in the Adnroid development.
3. I can send .xml file if needed.
   Also, don't mind comments inside the code...

This is the code:

```
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

   import android.os.AsyncTask;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   import java.util.*;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText user_input;
private EditText user_input1;
private Button Button;
private TextView result;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    user_input = findViewById(R.id.user_input);
    Button = findViewById(R.id.Button);
    result = findViewById(R.id.result);
    user_input1 = findViewById(R.id.user_input1);

    Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(user_input.getText().toString().trim().equals("")&&user_input1.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Введите хотя бы 2 варианта", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else{
                //creating method for randomly choosing one of the user inputs
                Random rand = new Random();
                EditText[] userInputs = {user_input, user_input1};
                int randomAnswer = rand.nextInt(userInputs.length);
                result = userInputs[randomAnswer];

                Log.v("EditText", result.getText().toString());
        }}
    });
}
private class getResult extends AsyncTask<String, String, TextView> {

    @Override
    protected TextView doInBackground(String... strings) {

        return result;
    }
}
}
```

Actually, I want to print the value in ResuRrect how to do that?

Comment: `text.setText(value);`

Answer (score 1):

can you please explain me where exactly you want to print values??
So that I can help you.

If you want to print whatever inserted by user you can use textview to display it.

for that just add two textview in xml find it by id in java and on button click perform set text on it.

for example you have two textview

```
TextView tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
TextView tv2 = findViewById(R.id.tv2);
```

and button click will be as follows

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(user_input.getText().toString().trim()) &&
                        TextUtils.isEmpty(user_input1.getText().toString().trim())) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Введите хотя бы 2 варианта", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    //creating method for randomly choosing one of the user inputs

                    tv1.setText(user_input.getText().toString().trim());
                    tv2.setText(user_input1.getText().toString().trim());
                    Log.e("EditText1", user_input.getText().toString().trim());
                    Log.e("EditText2", user_input2.getText().toString().trim());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: As you can see, I have an TextView called "Result". When user write into two EditText, program should use .Random method to print one of the Inputs into the TextView. But it doesn't print anything. I have tried using log.e but It still doesn't work. Should I add second TextView or is there any other way?

Comment: No need to add second textview just use this 

result.setText(userInputs[randomAnswer].getText().toString().trim());

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear but if you want to display text to the user, it is better to use TextView.
for the set text of EditText or TextView, you should use `setText` method.

```
user_input.setText("hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

So anyway I made it work. Now when user enters two values in EditText, program will randomly choose on of the inputs and print it in the TextView.
Here is the code:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
     if(user_input.getText().toString().trim().equals("")&&user_input1.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Введите хотя бы 2 варианта", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else{
                    //creating method for randomly choosing one of the user inputs
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    String[] key = {user_input1.getText().toString().trim(), user_input.getText().toString().trim()};
                    int randomAnswer = rand.nextInt(key.length);

                    result.setText(key[randomAnswer].toString().trim());
        }}
```